# Linear integer programming

Tags: optimization, linear-programming, integer-programming, discrete-optimization

I am trying to find the optimal solution for the following linear integer programming:

\begin{eqnarray} 
 &&\underset{x_i, \forall i} {\text{maximize}} ~
 \sum_{i=1}^N x_i a_i \\
&& \text{s.t.}
\sum_{i=1}^N i ~x_i \leq B, ~~~x_i  \in \mathbb N_{0},  ~\forall i. \nonumber
\end{eqnarray}

where $a_i$'s are known positive coefficients.

Comment: Have your tried Branch & Bound ?

Comment: @callculus not really, I was thinking of a relaxed solution of linear programming which would be sub-optimal, I'll try Branch and bound but it must be tedious for this problem !

Comment: It seems like a knapsack problem (where the value is $a_i$ and the cost is $b_i = i$) for which some efficient algorithms can be used.

Comment: Good luck for your calculation.

Answer (score 0):

The linear programming relaxation (relax variables to be continouos, i.e., just non-negative) would say to sort your variables in order via the ratio a_i / i .   Then add as much of each variable as you can in this order (with largest ratio).

This will give you the solution to the continuous relaxation.

Edited statement... how close to integrality is this?

Comment: Taking $N=2$, $a=(1,4)$, and $B=3$ yields optimal LP solution $x=(0,1.5)$ with objective value $6$ but optimal integer solution $x=(1,1)$ with objective value $5$.

Comment: https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Knapsack_problem#Greedy_approximation_algorithm